# Disable Quicklook Animation (space-key) High Sierra?

Tags: macos-high-sierra, quicklook

Would really love to disable the quicklook animation in High Sierra! It's been possible a couple of 10.x back, but those terminal commands doesn't seem to work in High Sierra.

Anyway to do it?

It's just so "slow" watching the animation every single time.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your System preferences -> Dock -> uncheck `Animate opening applications`

Comment: This suggestion is not related to the Quicklook-Animation!